# Timestamp retrieval methods

Tags: java, android, firebase, timestamp

I'm writing a method now to get the `timestamp` difference between when the post was uploaded to Firebase and Today's Date / Time. Based on a video I've watched and other posts on here, this is the method `getTimeDate` I have come up with. I pass it to my `ViewHolder`, although I am getting an `E/: getTimeDate: ParseException: Unparseable date: "1576534039437"`. Thought it was good, but it's just returning **today**.

What's the issue with my code?

The objective is for the `TextView` to say something like 6 hours ago, 32 minutes ago, 4 days ago, etc.

**PostAdapter.java**

```
if ("".equals(post.getTimestamp())) {
            holder.timestamp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            if (post.getPostid() != null) {
                holder.timestamp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String timestampDifference = getTimeDate();
                if (!timestampDifference.equals("0")) {
                    holder.timestamp.setText(timestampDifference + " days ago");
                } else {
                    holder.timestamp.setText("Today");
                }

            }
        }


 int position;

    //TIMESTAMP
    private String getTimeDate() {

        final Post post = mPost.get(position);
        final String TAG = "";

        String difference = "";
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        //Date format
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

        //Today's date
        Date today = calendar.getTime();
        simpleDateFormat.format(today);

        Date timestamp;
        try {
            if (post.getTimestamp() != null) {
                timestamp = simpleDateFormat.parse(post.getTimestamp().toString());
                difference = String.valueOf(Math.round(((today.getTime() - timestamp.getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24)));
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getTimeDate: ParseException: " + e.getMessage());
            difference = "0";
        }

        return difference;

    }
```

Comment: all you want to do is to get the difference in date/time ? what error you are getting?

Comment: @Jacks Between when the post was uploaded to Firebase and the current date / time. Has to be something like "6 hours ago", "32 minutes ago", "3 days ago", etc.

Comment: @Jacks Also, I'm getting a ```null pointer``` here, but idk why ```Date postTimestamp = simpleDateFormat.parse(post.getTimestamp().toString());```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that works in this situation.

```
      private Date date1, date2;
        .
        .
        .

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        .


        date1 = new Date(); // current datetime
        date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(datetimeFromPost); // date in string format from post.
        .

        printDifference(date1,date2);


        public void printDifference(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
                //milliseconds
                long different = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

                long secondsInMilli = 1000;
                long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
                long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
                long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;

                long elapsedDays = different / daysInMilli;
                different = different % daysInMilli;

                long elapsedHours = different / hoursInMilli;
                different = different % hoursInMilli;

                long elapsedMinutes = different / minutesInMilli;
                different = different % minutesInMilli;

                long elapsedSeconds = different / secondsInMilli;
                String difference= "";
                String diffDays = "";
                String diffHours = "";
                String diffMins = "00:";
                String diffSeconds = "00";

                if (elapsedDays > 0) {
                    if (elapsedDays == 1) {
                        diffDays = elapsedDays + " day ";
                    } else {
                        diffDays = elapsedDays + " days ";
                    }
                }
                if (elapsedHours > 0) {
                    diffHours = String.format("%02d", elapsedHours) + ":";
                }
                if (elapsedMinutes > 0) {
                    diffMins = String.format("%02d", elapsedMinutes) + ":";
                }
                if (elapsedSeconds > 0) {
                    diffSeconds = String.format("%02d", elapsedSeconds) + "";
                }

                difference= diffDays + diffHours + diffMins + diffSeconds + "ago"; 
    // here is the difference between datetime in "00:00:00 ago"

            }
```

Comment: its better and reusable if you have printDifference() as a separate method, just pass the date values to update the difference in dates, in any format you would like. As shown here i have added date, hours, minutes and also seconds.

Comment: I'm about to try it out. Let you know if it works. Thanks, bro

Comment: null pointer must be because of data issue, other than that this method gives you more understandable code, where you can edit to any format for the date stamp according to the requirement. in your case if you want only the 'days' you can skip other options available such as mins and hours. plus on the same day you can show only hours , if it is next day you can just show 'days'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204366/discussion-between-jacks-and-johnnnnyyyy).